# passing value of checkbox in spring to next page

Tags: spring, checkbox

the first page controller, I passed the checkbok in the post method,

```
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/new.html" }, method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public ModelAndView submitNew(final HttpServletRequest request,
            @RequestParam(value = "asSelectedCheckbox", required = false) boolean asSelectedCheckbox){
```

I passed the checkbox in the get method too, and then in the post method I did the if statement to do something if the checkbox is true, but The request always returns false in the second page controller, no matter if the box is checked or not.

The second page post method  controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/newNext.html" }, method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public ModelAndView submitNewNext(final HttpServletRequest request,
            @RequestParam(value = "asSelectedCheckbox", required = false) boolean asSelectedCheckbox){
```

my first page have the checkbox

```
    <input id="id" name="asSelectedCheckbox" type="checkbox" />
```

How can I  pass the right value of checkbox from first page to the next page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider each time controller is called as new "run" of your program which doesn't have state and doesn't know anything about who have called it before.

E.g. what if two users opened new.html simultaneously and one submitted form with checkbox checked, and other without? How should your newNext.html behave then?

Now the answer:

You can either store checkbox value in session bound to specific user, or pass it to view, so that when newNext.html being submitted you get that value.

You can add following code in submitNew() :

```
model.add("asSelectedCheckbox", asSelectedCheckbox);
```

Following code in new.jsp:

```
<form:hidden path="asSelectedCheckbox" />
```

And following code at the top of new.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

Comment: So, I do need to put the hidden filed just in the first jsp page, what about the second jsp that I want to do some process when the checkbox is selected? in the post method in the controller, Do I need to pass the asSelectedCheckbox as prameter here?

Comment: Your first controller page renders some HTML with form, that posts form data to second controller. So you have to make first controller to render page with pre-set hidden field in form to be posted to second controller.